# React native Navigation not working using react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation

Here is the code I'm not able to work that.

```
import React from 'react';
import{View,SafeAreaView,Text,Image,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import Icons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'; 
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';  
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'

import ListofHome from '../component/props/Index'
import Navbar from '../navigation/Navbar'
import Detail from './Details'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{
                flex:1,
                backgroundColor: '#f5fcff',
            }}>
                <Navbar/>

            <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={{marginTop:3,paddingHorizontal:20,flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight:'800',color:'red'}}>
                        JOB POSTS
                    </Text>
                    <Text>View more..</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            });
          }}>
                    <ListofHome
                    name="The list of master plans about me that is"/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>

            </ScrollView>

            </View>


        )
    }
}
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(  
    {  
       First:{
         screen:Detail,
       }

    } 
  );  
  export default (Home);
```

I could not find where is the error. It's not working it also not showing error but not working.

Answer (score 0):

If I guessed your problem right then here is solution :

```js
import React from 'react';
import{View,SafeAreaView,Text,Image,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import Icons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'; 
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';  
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'

import ListofHome from '../component/props/Index'
import Navbar from '../navigation/Navbar'
import Detail from './Details'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


class Home extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{
                flex:1,
                backgroundColor: '#f5fcff',
            }}>
                <Navbar/>

            <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={{marginTop:3,paddingHorizontal:20,flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight:'800',color:'red'}}>
                        JOB POSTS
                    </Text>
                    <Text>View more..</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            });
          }}>
                    <ListofHome
                    name="The list of master plans about me that is"/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>
                <ListofHome name="About your page that is do"/>

            </ScrollView>

            </View>


        )
    }
}
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(  
    {  
    Home: {
        screen: Home
    }, 
       Details:{
         screen:Detail,
       }
    }, 
    {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
 }
  );  
  export default AppNavigator
```

You have to export AppNavigator as default and navigate screen using same key that you defined for screens.